# how to handle a loop in flutter? need can be canceled?

Tags: flutter

I want to use flutter fulfilled a mqtt client. the client need send message to serve for loop.
I used "while" keyword for loop. but the flutter UI is pending during the while function.
if use isolate to work it, sending the cancel flag failed.
Does there anybody have the experience on it?

----------code------

onpressed -----> Future Function ----> use while loop---->the app pending cannot press anywhere---> the loop stop, the app recovery
I want start a mqtt client to send mqtt message for loop.
but when pressed the function, the while loop pended the app.
Expected results: the loop works in an async work, and the app can work rightly.
Actual results: the app is pending.
###UI

children: [

```
 SizedBox(width: 200),
    MaterialButton(
    child: Text('发送'),
    onPressed: () {
    BtnsendMsg();

   },
```

####onpressed function

```
     mc = new MqttClient(false);
BtnsendMsg() async {
mc.MsgSend(clientid, topic, msgname, '3');
print("back");
}
```

####loop function

```
 class MqttClient {
bool isStop;
MqttClient(this.isStop);
Future MsgSend(clientid, topic, msgname, interval) async {
isStop = false;
var cc = await clientGet(clientid);
var msg = await msgGet(msgname);
String host = "1.1.1.1";
String msgdata = "1111";
if (cc != null) {
host = cc.host!;
}
if (msg != null) {
msgdata = msg.msgdata!;
}
Future future = Future(() {
while (isStop == false) {
SendMsgOnce(host, clientid, topic, msgdata);
sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));
}
});
sleep(Duration(seconds: 30));
isStop = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are putting load on `main` thread by not using `async` and `await` while sending `request` to the `server`. Do the following changes to your code then it should get work.

```
class MqttClient {
    bool isStop;
    MqttClient(this.isStop);
    Future MsgSend(clientid, topic, msgname, interval) async {
    isStop = false;
    var cc = await clientGet(clientid);
    var msg = await msgGet(msgname);
    String host = "1.1.1.1";
    String msgdata = "1111";
     if (cc != null) {
         host = cc.host!;
        }
     if (msg != null) {
         msgdata = msg.msgdata!;
        }
    Future future = Future(() async {
     while (isStop == false) {
     await SendMsgOnce(host, clientid, topic, msgdata);
     sleep(Duration(seconds: 3));
    }
});
    sleep(Duration(seconds: 30));
    isStop = true; 
}
```

In your `on pressed` function you are using `async` but now `awaiting` for that

```
 mc = new MqttClient(false);
  BtnsendMsg() async {
   await mc.MsgSend(clientid, topic, msgname, '3');
   print("back");
}
```